firebase blocked Mime type react vue
I've been trying to host a vite react app that uses firestore on firebase. The website works locally when "npm run dev" is used. However, when I initialized the firebase hosting and deployed, it gave me a blank page. After inspecting the console, I got these two errors:
The stylesheet [My website url]/assets/index-789467f8.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
Loading module from [my website url]/assets/index-d9f611fa.js was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Help please!!!
I looked up the issue and tried multiple solutions, like base: "./" in viteconfig.ts, adding headers for each file type, and reinitializing the application. Can anyone help me with this issue?

My first guess would be that the app is not properly built on firebase. You might want to check your build process on firebase. Also, try running npm run build locally then npm run start to see if your app runs.
